# What, if any, experimental evidence is there that flies rub their legs together in order to clean them?

Tags: entomology, ethology

Everybody's seen a fly [rubbing its hands together](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6J2Xidhz3w) like Mr Burns. And almost everybody's heard the standard explanation - that it's cleaning itself. Now, this is certainly a very plausible explanation, but has it been demonstrated? I can't find any references to experiments seeking to prove this hypothesis. I'm asking because, not being very familiar with these matters, I'd love to know what methods were used to demonstrate something like this.

Comment: A pre-existing answer is linked in the above comment. I admit it doesn't cover the methods used to determine it's really cleansing. However, you cannot ask a fly why its doing something. One can just infer. As a consequence, there's no scientific literature on this afaik.

Comment: @Christiaan Well, you could imagine an experiment attempting to prove that the legs are indeed cleaner right after the rubbing ritual. Or you could see if flies rub their legs more frequently in dirty environments than in clean environments.

Comment: Oh yes, I can imagine a dozen of experiments, but I can't imagine any funding body to support it

Comment: @Christiaan Hey, if there's people [irradiating spider webs](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jez.1401760302/abstract) to track their path through the spider's digestive system, I'm sure someone's doing behavioral experiments on flies.

Comment: Haha nice one. In an attempt to answer the linked question I couldn't find anything.